# repeat display array of text in label forever

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I'm trying to repeat display array of text in label forever in xcode , 
first I added a `array` in `viewDidLoad` method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
_tweettest = @[@"tweet1",
 @"tweet2",
 @"tweet3",
 @"tweet4",
 @"tweet5"];

}
```

then i add `NSTimer` object in `viewDidAppear` method

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
 [super viewDidAppear:animated];
 NSDate *d = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 0.1];
  Timer1 = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate: d
 interval: 1
 target:self
 selector:@selector(Timer1Tasks)
 userInfo:nil
repeats:YES];
NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
[runner addTimer:Timer1 forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

}
```

then add method which will add text to label every 1 second

```
-(void) Timer1Tasks
{
static int count = 0;
NSString* letter = nil;


switch(count) {

    case 0: letter = _tweettest[0];
        _tweetlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",  letter];
        break;
    case 1: letter = _tweettest[1];
        _tweetlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",  letter];
        break;
    case 2: letter = _tweettest[2];
        _tweetlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",  letter];
        break;
    case 3: letter = _tweettest[3];
        _tweetlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",  letter];
        break;
    case 4: letter = _tweettest[4];
        _tweetlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",  letter];
        break;
}
count++;


}
```

now every thing is ok except that there is no loop to repeat view all text again forever from beginning.

any idea will be helpful.

Comment: Side note - your entire `switch` statement can be replaced with: `if (count < _tweettest.count) { _tweetLabel.text = _tweettest[count]; }`

Comment: Your goal is unclear. Are you trying to show "tweet1", then "tweet2", etc. through "tweet5", then go back and show "tweet1", etc.? In other words, you just want to endlessly loop through all of the tweets, 1 per second?

Comment: thanks rmaddy , your code more shortcuts .. but still need looping for view text

Comment: It would help if you answered my question.

Comment: yes .. I want endlessly loop to all tweets forever per 1 second

Comment: Ok, then see the answer by Wain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
-(void) Timer1Tasks
{
static int count = 0;
_tweetlabel.text = _tweettest[count];
count = ((count + 1) %  _tweettest.count);
}
```

Then make the static int an instance variable like it should be.

Comment: You stole my answer. :) I was waiting for a confirmation of the requirements. And good call on changing the static to an ivar.

Comment: Nice , it's work very well , thanks very much wain , and rmaddy